# How to calculate cumulative Total and % in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum, pareto-chart

This might be very simple...

I have the below summary table in Power BI and need to build a Pareto Chart, what I'm looking for is a way to create columns "D" and "E"... Thanks in advance!

The Count from column "B" is a measure I've created in PBI based on multiple filters. I've already tried some Calculate/Sum/Filter type of expressions with no luck.

[image]

My raw data looks like Image #2... I have the measures to build the summary table with the exception of column "I" - Running % - (for which I will also need the cumulative total of events per bucket).

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to successfully apply the calculations from DAXPATTERNS.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a well-known pattern for cumulative calculations in the [DAXPATTERNS](http://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/) blog.

Try this expression for `Running %` measure:

```
Running % =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [Percentage] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( YourTable), YourTable[Bucket] <= MAX ( YourTable[Bucket] ) )
)
```

And try this for Cumulative count measure:

```
Cumulative Count =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [Count] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( YourTable ), YourTable[Bucket] <= MAX ( YourTable[Bucket] ) )
)
```

Basically in each row you are summing those count or percent values that are less or equal than the bucket value in the evaluated row, which produces the cumulative total.

**UPDATE:** A posible solution matching your model.

Assuming your Event Count measure is defined as follows:

```
Event Count = COUNT(EventTable[Duration_Bucket])
```

You can create a cumulative count using `CALCULATE` function, which lets us calculate the `Running %` measure:

```
Cumulative Count =
CALCULATE (
    [Event Count],
    FILTER (
        ALL ( EventTable ),
        [Duration_Bucket] <= MAX ( EventTable[Duration_Bucket] )
    )
)
```

Now calculate the Running % measure using:

```
Running % =
DIVIDE (
    [Cumulative Count],
    CALCULATE ( [Event Count], ALL ( EventTable ) ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

You should get something like this in Power BI:

**Table visualization**

[image]

**Bar chart visualization**

[image]

Note my expressions use an `EventTable` which you should replace by the name of your table. Also note the `running %` line starts from 0 to 1 and there is only one Y-axis to the left.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, I've updated my initial question to provide my context...  unfortunately the formulas you refer to don't work, probably because of how my data is structured... the summary table is just something I can build from my raw data.

Comment: @MarceloAguilar, I've updated my answer, try implementing the edited answer.

Comment: I only changed the ALL for ALLSELECTED and is now working perfectly. THANK YOU!

Comment: Hi from 2019!  Any thoughts on how you would do this if you wanted it to start accumulating the "count" field when "duration_bucket" is at its greatest value?  That is, can I somehow have "duration_bucket" sorted descending, and then start accumulating the "count" values?