# How do you create a calculated cumulative total value column in a power bi matrix visualization?

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns, calculated-field, pareto-chart

I am pretty new to Power BI, but I'm learning alot fast. I do have one challenge at this point that has me stumped and I'm really not finding anything online that relates very closely.

I have created a basic matrix visualization that gives me sales totals by UPC code. The UPC code is in the Rows and the sales total is a Values column. I added a second instance of the sales as another Value to be calculated as a percent of the column total.

After sorting, I get a nice pivot table style look at the top selling UPC codes.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to add a calculated column that will give me a cumulative total of the percent so I can do a Top 80 (80/20) analysis. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

To be completely clear, I want a column to the right of the '%CT Sold Total' column that gives me '14.40%' on the first row, '27.46%' (14.40% + 13.06%) on the second row, '36.41%' (27.46% + 8.95%), and so on.

[image: Matrix Visualization in Power BI]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried these DAX Patterns yet? https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226792/how-to-calculate-cumulative-total-and-in-dax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate cumulative Total and % in DAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226792/how-to-calculate-cumulative-total-and-in-dax)

Answer (score 0):

Finally wrapped my head around this (powerbi.tips/2016/10/pareto-charting) and it is exactly what I was trying to do.